# Updating addresses of pointers after copying

Tags: c++, pointers, stdvector

Referring to the MWE below, I have a `Mesh` which includes `Point`s and `Cell`s. Now I partition the mesh into two with METIS and want to create two new meshes. Considering the circular pointer directions in the mesh, is there an easy way of updating the pointers of points and cells of the new meshes to new addresses?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Point;
struct Cell;

struct Mesh
{
    std::vector<Point> point;
    std::vector<Cell> cell;
};

struct Point
{
    Cell* parent_cell;
    int partition;
};

struct Cell
{
    std::vector<Point*> vertex;
    int partition;
};

int main()
{
    Mesh mesh;

    mesh.cell.resize(2); // create two triangles.
    mesh.point.resize(4); // 4 points instead of 6 because two of them will be shared.

    // let vertices know their parent cell.    
    mesh.point[0].parent_cell = &mesh.cell[0];
    mesh.point[1].parent_cell = &mesh.cell[0]; mesh.point[1].parent_cell = &mesh.cell[1];
    mesh.point[2].parent_cell = &mesh.cell[0]; mesh.point[2].parent_cell = &mesh.cell[1];
    mesh.point[3].parent_cell = &mesh.cell[1]; 

    // let cells know their vertices.
    mesh.cell[0].vertex.push_back(&mesh.point[0]);
    mesh.cell[0].vertex.push_back(&mesh.point[1]);
    mesh.cell[0].vertex.push_back(&mesh.point[2]);
    mesh.cell[1].vertex.push_back(&mesh.point[1]);
    mesh.cell[1].vertex.push_back(&mesh.point[2]);
    mesh.cell[1].vertex.push_back(&mesh.point[3]);    

    // partition mesh into two.
    // give partition number to points.
    // all but one of the vertices belong to partition 0.
    mesh.point[0].partition = 0;
    mesh.point[1].partition = 0;
    mesh.point[2].partition = 0;
    mesh.point[3].partition = 1; // only this vertex belongs to partition 1.
    // give partition number to cells.
    mesh.cell[0].partition = 0;
    mesh.cell[1].partition = 1;

    // create two new meshes.
    // filter points and cells according to partition number.
    // but how to update pointers?    

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to store indexes to the other vectors instead of pointers. They remain valid after copying or when the vector reallocates the backing memory.

I did similar thing in one of my projects and was worried a bit about performance because of the extra indirection. It turned out to be even faster than the pointers! Probably because I replaced 8B pointers with 4B integers and saved on memory loads.

---

If you insist on using pointers to elements of `std::vector`, you can remap them after copy like this:

```
// Mesh copy constructor
Mesh::Mesh(const Mesh &other) {
    point = other.point;
    cell = other.cell;

    for(Point &p : point) {
        p.parent_cell = p.parent_cell - other.cell.data() + cell.data();
    }

    for(Cell &c : cell) {
        for(Point* &p : c.vertex) {
            p = p - other.point.data() + point.data();
        }
    }
}
```

Be warned that this is fragile code. If something in the structure changes and this method is not updated accordingly, it will lead to ugly bugs.